# How do I copy files from the source with different dates than the destination using the Command Line

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, robocopy, xcopy

So I am not able to find a switch in Robocopy or xCopy that lets me copy files from the source to the destination, only if the date of the file is different. Regardless if that file is newer or older than the one in the destination.

Situation 1: It should skip any files in the destination that match the date in the source. But if there is a older file in the destination than in the source, it will copy that.

Situation 2: Further, if there is a newer file in the destination than the source, it will copy that one as well.

I see there is a switch to do the former but I don't see one for the second situation.

Unfortunately, the xCopy /d switch will not work in this case either. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this?

I would prefer the answer to be in batch programming but if it is in Powershell, vb.NET, or C#, that's okay too. Any advice will be welcome.

Thank you!

Mark

Comment: The `FileInfo` dotnet class has a `LastWriteTime` property that is a `DateTime` type you could compare to (this is what is returned from `Get-ChildItem`/`Get-Item`)

Comment: So basically you want to skip files that have the same date but different size/content, right? what about `robocopy /XC` then?

Comment: Is it the date that is really important? Or do you just want to copy any file that is ***different*** from source to destination? If you want to copy any file that is different then I would get the hash of each file and copy if they are different.

Comment: I agree with @aschipfl.  Robocopy already doesn't copy files that it doesn't think are necessary to copy (same name, same size, same length).  `robocopy /XC` will exclude files that have the same timestamp but different sizes.  I don't know why you would want to do that over robocopy's defaults of updating changed files with the same timestamp, but it can be done.  [This answer](https://superuser.com/a/445137/75477) has a nice table and explanation for robocopy's behavior.

Comment: Nice. Thank you guys. I will try out robocopy XC and see if that works. I'll let you know! The reason I want it to re-copy files from the source even if the source file is older is because these files reside on the employee's computer. If they make a change to their file, that will update the timestamp. If they do that after I update a file in the source, then the file is not going to download to their computer and they will miss the update. Hope that makes sense. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long time, I finally figured out the answer I was looking for yesterday. It is...

```
ROBOCOPY /XX /MIR YourSourceFolder YourDestinationFolder
```

It's a combination of both the /XX and /MIR switches with RoboCopy.

The /XX switch will not allow RoboCopy to touch any extra file that already exists in the folder.

Then, the /MIR switch will bring a mirror copy from the SourceFolder to the DestinationFolder. Date and times will match in both folders. Amazing!

My mistake before was that I was attempting to just find a single switch that would do this for me rather than combining available switches.